# Query with PHP using PDO are not inserted in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

I insert with **PHP** some data in my **MySQL** database, using **PDO**.

```
$connection->query(
    "INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.first_name (first_name)
    VALUES ('" . $firstName . "');

    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.last_name (last_name)
    VALUES ('" . $lastName . "');

    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.section (section)
    VALUES ('" . $section . "');

    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.order (creation_date, wished_delivery_date, status, email, first_name_id, last_name_id, section_id)
    VALUES ('" . $creationDate . "', '" . $wishedDeliveryDate . "', 'En attente', '" . $email . "', (SELECT first_name_id FROM eOrderManagement.first_name WHERE first_name LIKE '" . $firstName . "'), (SELECT last_name_id FROM eOrderManagement.last_name WHERE last_name LIKE '" . $lastName . "'), (SELECT section_id FROM eOrderManagement.section WHERE section LIKE '" . $section . "'));

    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.equipment (description, imputation, cost, maintenance_cost, order_id)
    VALUES ('" . $description . "', '" . $imputation . "', '" . $cost . "', '" . $maintenanceCost . "', (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM eOrderManagement.order));"
    );
```

The three first requests are inserted in my database, but the two last are not.
I tried to insert them manually in the *MySQL Commande Line*, directly with data on the query (unlike with variables in PHP), and all the query insert the data correctly.

Any idea why this two query doesn't insert anything ?
The two query I am talking about are :

```
    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.order (creation_date, wished_delivery_date, status, email, first_name_id, last_name_id, section_id)
    VALUES ('" . $creationDate . "', '" . $wishedDeliveryDate . "', 'En attente', '" . $email . "', (SELECT first_name_id FROM eOrderManagement.first_name WHERE first_name LIKE '" . $firstName . "'), (SELECT last_name_id FROM eOrderManagement.last_name WHERE last_name LIKE '" . $lastName . "'), (SELECT section_id FROM eOrderManagement.section WHERE section LIKE '" . $section . "'));

    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.equipment (description, imputation, cost, maintenance_cost, order_id)
    VALUES ('" . $description . "', '" . $imputation . "', '" . $cost . "', '" . $maintenanceCost . "', (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM eOrderManagement.order));"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word for SQL. So you have to quote your table name `order`

```
`eOrderManagement.order`
```

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO `eOrderManagement.order` (creation_date, wished_delivery_date, status, email, first_name_id, last_name_id, section_id)
    VALUES ('" . $creationDate . "', '" . $wishedDeliveryDate . "', 'En attente', '" . $email . "', (SELECT first_name_id FROM eOrderManagement.first_name WHERE first_name LIKE '" . $firstName . "'), (SELECT last_name_id FROM eOrderManagement.last_name WHERE last_name LIKE '" . $lastName . "'), (SELECT section_id FROM eOrderManagement.section WHERE section LIKE '" . $section . "'));

    INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.equipment (description, imputation, cost, maintenance_cost, order_id)
    VALUES ('" . $description . "', '" . $imputation . "', '" . $cost . "', '" . $maintenanceCost . "', (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM `eOrderManagement.order`));"
```

Moreover, your queries are vulnerable for SQL injections. So I suggest you to use prepared statements with parameters.

for example:

```
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO eOrderManagement.equipment 
                          (description, 
                           imputation, 
                           cost, 
                           maintenance_cost, 
                           order_id) 
                   VALUES (:description, 
                           :imputation, 
                           :cost, 
                           :maintenanceCost, 
                           (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM `eOrderManagement.order`)
                          )'
             );

$query->bindValue(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
```

OR

```
$query->execute(':description' => $description, :imputation => $imputation, ...);
```

Another point what if there are two insert processes executed simultaneously?

```
 SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM `eOrderManagement.order`
```

would return incorrect value. Use [`lastInsertId()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) function of PDO.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your problem is FAR deeper than silly syntax issue.

First of all, such a database structure makes absolutely no sense.
Having tables consists of one single field **won't let you to get your data back!**

So, instead of first three you have to make **ONE** table first, contains all your fields.

Then create **ONE** insert query that have to utilize **prepared statements** instead of interpolating variables like you do here.

And you ought to use LAST_INSERT_ID()/PDO::insertId() to handle table relations, instead of these selects.

Comment: Yes, the single field tables are a bit weird, in fact it is to do some auto-completion. In the context of my project, it make sense. Thanks for the LAST_INSERT_ID()/PDO::insertId()

Comment: IT DOESN'T make ANY sense in ANY context. Your idea on whatever "auto-completion" is just wrong. One can make auto-completion  with regular tables all right